# How to cast super class object to sub class object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, oop, kotlin

Here I am trying to converting superclass object to subclass. I am getting the runtime error as "class can not be cast".

Eg :

```
class Animal {}
class Cat : Animal() {}

class abc {
fun abcd(): Animal {
    return Animal()
}

fun getData() {
    val cat: Cat = abcd() as Cat     //Giving me runtime error.
}
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce with kotlin 1.4.10 (aside from the error about not being able to inherit from `Animal` since it isn't `open`). There is a `ClassCastException` at runtime though.

Comment: The problem is the `abcd` method because it always returns an `Animal` are there any conditions where that can return any of the child types?

Answer (score 5):

**You can't cast a base class 'instance' to a descendant class**, because a base class does not necessarily implement the behaviors of its descendants neither knows anything about them.

In your specific example the method **abcd()** returns an instance of the base class **Animal**, and therefore such can't be cast to **Cat**, since **Animal** may not have any of the behaviors defined in **Cat**.

An example, imagine you had also a **Dog** class, and both **Cat** and **Dog** implement different methods such as **dog.fetch()** and **cat.jump()**. Such behaviors don't exist in the base class **Animal**, and therefore it can't be explicitly cast to a specific animal.

The opposite is valid, so casting **Cat** to **Animal**, because **Cat** inherits the behaviors of its base class **Animal**.

Instead, what you can do is to instantiate a **Cat** in **abcd()**, and still return **Animal**:

```
fun abcd(): Animal {
    return Cat()
}
```

This is valid, and the casting will work. But, you must pay attention to avoid potential **ClassCastException**'s at runtime if mixing up derived classes, for example if instantiating a **Dog** while the return type is **Animal** and try to use it as **Cat**.

**Small remark:** I'm assuming the reason **Animal** isn't **open** in your example is just a copy/paste mistake, as it clearly needs such keyword to allow inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you are trying to do is something like creating a type and based on what sub-type then do something, like this:

```
sealed class Animal

data class Cat(val...) : Animal()
data class Dog(val...) : Animal()

class YourMapper {
    fun animal(condition: Type): Animal {
        return when(condition) {
            ... -> Dog(...)
            ... -> Cat(...)
        }
    }

    fun getData(condition: Type): Animal {
        return animal(condition)
    }
```

And then the usage is

```
val data = YourMapper().getData(condition)
when(data) {
  is Dog -> {/*do something with your dog*/}
  is Cat -> {/*do something with your cat*/} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it's the first Google hit for the search "Kotlin how to cast superclass to subclass", so for prosperity:

**How to cast to subcalss in Kotlin**
use the "as" keyword as in the original question:

```
if(animal is Cat) {
    Cat cat = animal as Cat
}
```

**The original question**
Short answer, you can't cast a superclass **object** to a subclass **object**. Casting only changes the type of the reference *to* the object, the object itself remains unchanged.

The Animal class in the question should almost certainly be marked as abstract. That way there's no possibility to accidentally instantiate non-specific animals, which is what happens in the question and causes the exception.

An Animal *reference* variable can absolutely be cast to a Cat, provided the object it references is a Cat. But in the question a non-specific Animal is instantiated, and then later attempted to cast to a Cat, but as it is not referencing a Cat object, this understandably throws an exception.

So unlike, say, casting an Int to a Double where the cast seemingly changes the type of the object, casting object references doesn't actually "*change*" the object, only how finely-grained your reference to it is.
Casting cannot turn a Dog into a Cat, it can only change you from examining an animal as a generic Animal, viewing properties commont to ALL animals, to examining it as a Cat or a Dog and additionally having access to the properties only Cats or Dogs have.