# Unsure of the syntax when creating a instance of a class that inherits Application (Android studio kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I was wondering why must an instance of the application class be instantiated like this?

**Instantiating the `InventoryApplication` class**

```
private val test = activity?.application as InventoryApplication
```

**InventoryApplication class**

```
class InventoryApplication : Application() {

val database: ItemRoomDatabase by lazy { ItemRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this) }
}
```

Is there a reason why it can't be instantiated normally like
`val instance =InventoryApplication()`?

Comment: The first example is not instantiating an `InventoryApplication` class - it's defining a variable by accessing the activity's reference to it and casting it. It has been instantiated somewhere else. You should never instantiate an `Application` class, that is the responsibility of the Android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never instantiate an Application. The Application is representative of your whole app and is instantiated by the OS. If you try to instantiate your own Application (or Activity or Service), you will have a useless instance that has incorrect and null references that will have unexpected behaviors and throw exceptions that crash your app.

This code:

```
private val test = activity?.application as InventoryApplication
```

does not instantiate your Application. It is getting the pre-existing instance from your Activity and *casting* it to the more specific type that represents your specific application.

Casting does not convert or change an object. It is only a promise to the compiler that the instance already is the other type that you claim with the `as` keyword. The reason `activity.application` returns Application instead of your more specific InventoryApplication is that the property is defined in the Android SDK, so it cannot return a type that isn't a part of the SDK. It is in fact returning InventtoryApplication. The compiler just doesn't know that until you cast it.

It is technically unsafe to cast `activity?.application` to a non-nullable type like you are doing in this code. It is similar to:

```
private val test = activity!!.application as InventoryApplication
```

and will crash if `activity` happens to be null when this code is run. If this is in a Fragment, the code is acceptable to use only while the Fragment is attached to an Activity. It is more typical to use `requireActivity()` instead of `activity` when you need the Activity reference and you know the Fragment is currently attached. It better communicates that you understand the risk and have checked to be sure it is called at a safe stage of the Fragment lifecycle.

If you are unsure if the Fragment is attached at the time this code is called, it would be safer to use `as InventoryApplication?` and handle the nullability as needed.

———-
Casting example. Imagine you have these two classes and function.

```
open class Animal
class Cat: Animal {
    fun meow() = println("Meow!")
}

fun generateAnimal(): Animal {
    return Cat()
}
```

We have a function that is returning a Cat, but when you call it in your code, the compiler only knows that it is an Animal, not the more specific type Cat, because the function is declared with a return type of Animal. This is a case where you can successfully cast the Animal to a Cat because it already is a Cat. After casting, the compiler will allow you to treat the instance as a Cat and call the `meow()` function on it.

Comment: However, what is the point of actually inheriting the Application class in the first place? Can't we just not inherit from Application? What purpose does inheriting from application do?(Refering to the InventoryApplication class)


`class InventoryApplication  {

val database: ItemRoomDatabase by lazy { ItemRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this) }
}
`

Comment: And one more question, when inheriting from the Application base class, is the instance of the `class InventoryApplication` also an instance of `Application`? So an instance of the subtype is also an instance of the supertype?

Comment: It gives you a place to set up singletons, a logging library, or whatever you need to be set up for the lifetime of the app, regardless of entry point. Some apps can be started by a Broadcast Receiver or Service being triggered, or an Activity other than the home Activity.

Comment: Yes, a subclass is also its superclass. This is why you almost never have to cast something to its super type to be able to use it as that super type. The only exception I can think of is when two functions have the same name but one has a more specific type for the argument, but you want to use the version for the super type explicitly. Very rare circumstance.

Comment: It actually just occurred to me, how is it possible to cast a supertype into a subtype, isn't it not possible? I was reading through this
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264203/how-to-cast-super-class-object-to-sub-class-object-in-kotlin)

Comment: You can only cast to a subtype if the instance already is that subtype, but the compiler doesn’t know it at this spot in the code. You are promising the compiler that it actually already is the subtype. That’s exactly what you’re doing in your code above. Android instantiates InventoryApplication because that’s what’s declared in the manifest, but the `activity.application` property is only defined to return Application so at that point the compiler doesn’t know it has the subtype until you tell it by casting.

Comment: I am sorry I don't think I quite understand what you are saying. So `activity.application` returns an instance of `application`, isn't the `application` instance a supertype of the `InventoryApplication`? What do you mean by this "You can only cast to a subtype if the instance already is that subtype,"?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. It is analogous to what is happening with Application.